# Failed to add server in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, database-replication, nosql

When I try add server to couchbase : Server Nodes/ -> Add Server 
I add Server IP Address : **XX.XXX.X.XXX:port** and username/password 
but when I click Add Server I have a warning like "picture" 
I try switch with many server but same stack always ...

```
Attention - Failed to reach erlang port mapper. Timeout connecting to "10.107.2.237" on port "4369". This could be due to an incorrect host/port combination or a firewall in place between the servers.

Warning \u2013 Adding a server to this cluster means all data on that server will be removed.
```

thx for your help
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

4369 is the port for erlang node interconnection and must be accessible from all your nodes. So as described in error message you must check, if that port is accessible from other nodes. Also, are you sure that couchbase started on that new node?

You can read more about that port on http://erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html

Comment: Yes Couchbase is started. I Think it is a two-port Access Problem ( 4369 , 11210 ) Because it is a machine of production and I Think That flows are not open on this machine . I Can not writing in the base (in this machine).